# Allow duplicate columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm splitting a large CSV (containing stock financial data) file into smaller chunks. The format of the CSV file is different. Something like an Excel pivot table. The first few rows of the first column contain some headers.

Company name, id, etc. are repeated across the following columns. Because one single company has more than one attribute, not like one company has one column only.

After the first few rows, the columns then start resembling a typical data frame where headers are in columns instead of rows.

Anyways, what I'm trying to do is to make Pandas allow duplicate column headers and not make it add ".1", ".2", ".3", etc after the headers. I know Pandas does not allow this natively, **is there a workaround?** I tried to set header = None on read_csv but it throws a tokenization error which I think makes sense. I just can't think of an easy way.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

csv_path = "C:\\Users\\ThirdHandBD\\Desktop\\Data Splitting\\pd-split\\chunk4.csv"

#df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, header=1, dtype='unicode', sep=';', low_memory=False, error_bad_lines=False)
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, header = 1, dtype='unicode', sep=';', index_col=False)
print("I read in a dataframe with {} columns and {} rows.".format(
len(df.columns), len(df)
))

filename = 1

#column increment
x = 30 * 59

for column in df:
    loc = df.columns.get_loc(column)
    if loc == (x * filename) + 1:
        y = filename - 1
        a = (x * y) + 1
        b = (x * filename) + 1
        date_df = df.iloc[:, :1]
        out_df = df.iloc[:, a:b]
        final_df = pd.concat([date_df, out_df], axis=1, join='inner')
        out_path = "C:\\Users\\ThirdHandBD\\Desktop\\Data Splitting\\pd-split\\chunk4-part" + str(filename) + ".csv"
        final_df.to_csv(out_path, index=False)
        #out_df.to_csv(out_path)
        filename += 1

# This should be the same as df, but with only the first column.
# Check it with similar code to above.
```

**EDIT:**

From, https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19383, I add:

```
        final_df.columns = final_df.iloc[0]
        final_df = final_df.reindex(final_df.index.drop(0)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

So, full code:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_path = "C:\\Users\\ThirdHandBD\\Desktop\\Data Splitting\\pd-split\\chunk4.csv"

#df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, header=1, dtype='unicode', sep=';', low_memory=False, error_bad_lines=False)
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, header = 1, dtype='unicode', sep=';', index_col=False)
print("I read in a dataframe with {} columns and {} rows.".format(
len(df.columns), len(df)
))

filename = 1

#column increment
x = 30 * 59

for column in df:
    loc = df.columns.get_loc(column)
    if loc == (x * filename) + 1:
        y = filename - 1
        a = (x * y) + 1
        b = (x * filename) + 1
        date_df = df.iloc[:, :1]
        out_df = df.iloc[:, a:b]
        final_df = pd.concat([date_df, out_df], axis=1, join='inner')
        out_path = "C:\\Users\\ThirdHandBD\\Desktop\\Data Splitting\\pd-split\\chunk4-part" + str(filename) + ".csv"
        final_df.columns = final_df.iloc[0]
        final_df = final_df.reindex(final_df.index.drop(0)).reset_index(drop=True)
        final_df.to_csv(out_path, index=False)
        #out_df.to_csv(out_path)
        filename += 1

# This should be the same as df, but with only the first column.
# Check it with similar code to above.
```

Now, the entire first row is gone. But, the expected output is for the header row to be replaced with the reset index, without the ".1", ".2", etc.

**Screenshot:**

The SimFin ID row is no longer there.

[image]

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50353740/pandas-to-excel-ignore-allow-duplicate-column-names

Answer (score 9):

This is how I did it:

```
    final_df.columns = final_df.columns.str.split('.').str[0]
```

Reference:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html

Comment: This assumes that no other column has a genuine "." character.

Comment: Extraordinary method!

Comment: This will fail if the column name has a really "." character in it.

Answer (score 1):

Below solution would ensure that other column names with symbol period ('.') in the dataframe do not get modified

```
import pandas as pd
from csv import DictReader

csv_file_loc = "file.csv"

# Read csv  
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_loc)

# Get column names from csv file using DictReader  
col_names = DictReader(open(csv_file_loc, 'r')).fieldnames

# Rename columns  
df.columns = col_names
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm pretty late to the draw on this one, but I'm leaving the solution I came up with in case anyone else wanders across this as I have.

Firstly, the linked question has a pretty nice and dynamic solution that seems to work well even for high column counts. I came across that after I made my solution, haha. Check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50353740/pandas-to-excel-ignore-allow-duplicate-column-names?noredirect=1&lq=1). Another answer on this thread utilizes the [csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read and use the column names from that, as it doesn't seem to modify duplicates like Pandas does. That should work fine, but I just wanted to avoid using any extra libraries, especially considering I was originally using csv and then upgrade to Pandas for better functionality.

Now here's my solution. I'm sure it could be done more nicely but this does the job for what I needed and is pretty dynamic, from what I can tell. It basically goes through the columns, checks if it can split the string based on *the rightmost* "." (that's the [rpartition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition)), then does a few more checks from there.

It checks:

1. Is this string in the colMap? The colMap keeps track of all of the column names, duplicate or not. If this comes back true, then that means it's a duplicate of another column that came before it.
2. Is the string after the rightmost "." a number? All of the columns are strings, so this just makes sure that whatever it is can be converted into a number to prevent grabbing some other random column that meets previous criteria but isn't actually a dupe from Pandas. eg. "DupeCol" and "DupeCol.Stuff" wouldn't get picked up, but "DupeCol" and "DupeCol.1" would.
3. Does the number that comes after the rightmost "." match up to the current count of duplicates in the colMap? Seeing as the colMap contains all of the names of the columns, duplicates or not, this will ensure that we're not grabbing a user-named column that managed to overlap with the ".number" convention that Pandas uses. Eg. if a user had named two columns "DupeCol" and "DupeCol.6", it wouldn't get picked up *unless* there were 6 "DupeCol"s preceding "DupeCol.6", indicating that it almost *had* to be Pandas that named it that way, as opposed to the user. *This part is definitely a bit overkill, but I felt like being extra thorough.*

```html
colMap = []

for col in df.columns:
    if col.rpartition('.')[0]:
        colName = col.rpartition('.')[0]
        inMap = col.rpartition('.')[0] in colMap
        lastIsNum = col.rpartition('.')[-1].isdigit()
        dupeCount = colMap.count(colName)

        if inMap and lastIsNum and (int(col.rpartition('.')[-1]) == dupeCount):
            colMap.append(colName)
            continue
    colMap.append(col)
        
df.columns = colMap
```

Hopefully this helps someone! Feel free to comment if you think it could use any improvements. I don't entirely love using "continue" in my code, but I'm not sure if that's because it's actually bad practice or just me reading random people complain about it too much. I think it doesn't make the code too unreadable here and prevents the need for duplicating the "else" statement; but let me know if there's a way to improve that or anything otherwise. I'm always looking to learn!

Answer (score 0):

If you know types of all data you may consider loading the csv without header first.

```py
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, header=None)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]  # replace column with first row
df = df.drop(0)  # remove the first row
```

(Note that drop is to remove the row, given that your index is unique, and may not be true if you use `index_col` argument of `pd.read_csv`)

caveats: The above solution causes you to lose dtypes infomations.

There is some solution to fix the above problem.

```
# turn each column into numeric
df = df.apply(lambda col: pd.to_numeric(col, errors='ignore'), axis=0)
```

Otherwise, you may consider reading the csv twice to get the dtype information and apply the correct convertion.