# pandas to_excel() ignore/allow duplicate column names

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Is there way to ignore duplicate column names after using to_excel() function of pandas?

Say, I have **old_wb.xlsx**:

```
>> df1 = pd.read_excel('wb1.xlsx')
        ---------------------merged header--------------------
        col1    col2   col3   col1   col4   col1   col2   col5
        test    test   test   test   test   test   test   test
```

and say I did **some processing** to my Excel file, for example, remove the merged header and save it to another Excel file:

```
>> df1.to_excel('new_wb.xlsx', 'Sheet1', merged_cells=False, header=None, index=False)
```

The column names of **new_wb.xlsx** looks like this:

```
        col1    col2   col3   col1.1   col4   col1.2   col2.1   col5
        test    test   test   test     test   test     test     test
```

It added `.1` to the duplicate column names and it also increments as the duplicate column name goes.

I tried renaming the column name before using `to_excel()` but it didn't work. It seems the renaming of duplicates happens in `to_excel()`.

```
>> df1.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('.1',''))
```

Upon searching, I found an argument for `to_excel()` which is `mangle_dupe_cols=False`, unfortunately it returned:

```
ValueError: Setting mangle_dupe_cols=False is not supported yet
```

Any help on how to ignore duplicate column names in saving `to_excel()'

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: @Chris `pd.__version__`  says, 0.22.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *@Ricky Aguilar* has a great solution. I took his solution and just made it more **dynamic**.

Now you can **rename all your duplicate headers, without even knowing what their values are**

```
def dataframe_allowing_duplicate_headers():
    # To Hold All The Possible Duplicate Tags ['.1', '.2', '.3', ...]
    dup_id_range = []

    # Load Your Excel File Using Pandas
    dataframe = pandas.read_excel("path_to_excel_file", sheet_name="sheetname")

    # Generate And Store All The Possible Duplicate Tags ['.1', '.2', '.3', ...]
    for count in range(0, len(dataframe.columns)):
        dup_id_range.append( '.{}'.format(count) )

    # Search And Replace All Duplicate Headers To What It Was Set As Originally
    def rename(dataframe, character_number):
        duplicate_columns_chars = list(
            filter(lambda v: v[(len(v)-character_number):] in dup_id_range,
            dataframe.columns))

        for duplicate_column in duplicate_columns_chars:
            dataframe = dataframe.rename(
                columns={duplicate_column:duplicate_column[:-character_number]})
        return dataframe


    # Replace The Possible Duplicates Respectfully Based On Columns Count
    if len(dup_id_range) > 0:
        dataframe = rename(dataframe, 2)
        if len(dup_id_range) > 9:
            dataframe = rename(dataframe, 3)
            if len(dup_id_range) > 99:
                dataframe = rename(dataframe, 4)
                # If You Have More Than A Thousand Columns (lol)
                #if len(dup_id_range) > 999:
                #    dataframe = rename(dataframe, 5)

    return dataframe
```

**USAGE:**

```
# This Dataframe Will Have All Your Headers, Allowing Your Duplicates
my_dataframe = dataframe_allowing_duplicate_headers()
```

Comment: Great answer, and I have >1000 columns!

Comment: Thanks @MartienLubberink ... > 1000 Columns ... that sounds insane ... but i just saw you're an Associate Professor of Accounting ... now it all makes sense.

Comment: Haha, lol, the data was wide, and I had to convert it too long. Pandas does this excellently thanks to stack, unstack, set_index, reset_index, and pivot

Answer (score 4):

It's workable using:

```
df1.rename(columns={'old_name':'new_name'})
```

Although, it doesn't look good as I have 10 columns to rename.